# iS It a Complete metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $E=\mathcal{C}([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ and $w\in E$ do not vanish on  $[a,b]$. 
define $d_w(f,g)=\sup_{t\in [a,b]} |w(t)(f(t)-g(t))|$

how to see if $(E,d_w)$ is complete or not ?

----> i take $(f_n)_n$ a Cauchy sequence from E, for any fixed $t\in [a,b]$ then $(f_n(t))$ converge to a real $f(t)$

but i don't know to continue.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that $(E, d_w)$ is complete, that is, show that every Cauchy sequence from $E$ converges in $E$.
Taking the 'normal' metric $\tilde d = \sup_{t\in [a,b]} |(f(t)-g(t))|$, what do we know? We know:

- A Cauchy-sequence $(f_n)_n$ of functions $[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ converges uniformly to a function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$
- If a sequence of continuous $(f_n)_n$ on $[a,b]$ converges uniformly to an $f$, then $f$ is continuous

Suppose now, we have a Cauchy-sequence $(f_n)_n$ in $(E, d_w)$.

**Step 1:** We want to show it is also a Cauchy-sequence in $(E, \tilde d)$.
 *Proof*: Let $\epsilon \gt 0$. $w \in E$ is continuous, so let $$\alpha := \max_{t\in [a,b]}{|w(t)|} \gt 0$$ and $$\beta := \min_{t\in [a,b]}{|w(t)|} \gt 0$$ (because $w$ doesn't vanish).
As $(f_n)_n$ is Cauchy-sequence in $(E, d_w)$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$, so that $d_w(f_n, f_m) \lt \frac{\epsilon \cdot \beta}{2}$ $\forall n,m \geq N$. But then also for all $n,m \geq N$ and $t \in [a,b]$: 
$$ |f_n(t) - f_m(t)| = \frac{|w(t)|}{|w(t)|} \cdot |f_n(t) - f_m(t)| \leq \frac{|w(t)|}{\beta} \cdot |f_n(t) - f_m(t)| = \frac{1}{\beta} \cdot |w(t)(f_n(t)-f_m(t))|$$$$ \leq \frac{1}{\beta} \cdot d_w(f_n, f_m) \lt \frac{\epsilon \cdot \beta}{2\beta} = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Building the maximum provides $\tilde d(f_n, f_m) \lt \epsilon$. $\square$

**Step 2:** We now know that $(f_n)_n$ is a Cauchy-sequence and thus converges to a $f \in E$ (in regard to metric $\tilde d$). We want to show that $(f_n)_n$ also converges to $f$ in regard to metric $d_w$. But this follows easily from seeing that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $t \in [a,b]$:
$$|w(t)(f_n(t)-f(t))| = |w(t)|\cdot|(f_n(t)-f(t))| \leq \alpha |f_n(t)-f(t)| \leq \alpha \cdot \tilde d(f_n, f)$$

Comment: please in case w=1 how to see that $f$ is continuous ?

Comment: See the second bullet item. All your $f_n$s are continuous. They converge uniformly to an $f$, so $f$ is continuous as well.

Comment: but how to prove it please

Comment: See for example: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Real_Analysis/Uniform_Convergence

Comment: @Vrouvrou Everything clear then?

Comment: please why when w=1 the space is complete ?

Comment: This proof can be found in any basic calculus book, multiple threads in this forum or for example here: https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2008/09/08/cauchys-condition-for-uniform-convergence/

Comment: But it is without $\sup $ in the files you give me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36657/discussion-between-johnnycrab-and-vrouvrou).

Comment: @Vrouvrou Just a quick note: after the answer, comments and chat; if you wanna leave an upvote, I'd be very grateful :)